# CodeIgniter file insert to database but not the folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

```
public function index(){
    $image = null;//tem var
    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|jpe|png';
    $config['max_size']      = '4000000';

    $this->load->library('upload',$config);

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Album Title', 'required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        $data['imagePath'] = base_url().'assets/uploads/';
        $data['album'] = $this->gallery->getAlbum();
        $this->load->view('admin/album', $data);
    }else{
        if (! $this->upload->do_upload('image')){//file upload
            $this->image = null;
        }else{
            $tem = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $this->image = $tem["upload_data"]["file_name"];
        }//end else

         $data=array(
            'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'featured' => $this->image,
            'created_on' =>  date("Y-m-d")
         );

         if($this->gallery->createAlbum($data)){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('created','Album Has Been Created');
            redirect("admin");
         }
    }   
}

public function viewGallery($album_id){
    $config['upload_path']          = FCPATH.'assets/uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|jpe|png';
    $config['max_size']             = 10000;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $data['imagePath'] = base_url().'assets/uploads/';
    $data['images'] = $this->gallery->getGalleryWithId($album_id);
    $data['album_id'] = $album_id;
    $this->load->view('addGallery', $data);
}
```

Uploads to the database but not the folder specified... 
Don't know what to do next.. 
Any help will really be good.
I don't know where to put the path foldername wherein the file should be uploaded. The only thing that is uploading to the database works.

Thanks in advance

Comment: take reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21753992/codeigniter-file-paths

Answer (score 1):

Try to add FCPATH

```
$config['upload_path'] = FCPATH.'/assets/uploads/';
```

Comment: i dont knw if it has something to do with permissions

Comment: but wen i integerate it.... upload to database works but not file upload

Comment: I tried using `FCPATH./assets/uploads/';` But that won't work because `FCPATH` has a trailing `/` after it. Which makes the path incorrect. It needs to be `FCPATH.'assets/uploads/';`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.
First Define any folder name in which you want to insert the file.
Like in this case i have made 'title' the folder name at my end.

```
if($this->form_validation->run())     
        {  
            $title=$this->input->post('title');

            $config['upload_path']          = './assets/courses/'.$title;
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
            $config['max_size']             = 1000;
            $config['max_width']            = 500;
            $config['max_height']           = 300;
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            if (!is_dir('./assets/courses/'.$title)) {
             mkdir('./assets/courses/'.$title, 0777, TRUE);
         }
```

Hope So this will help You.